# After closing Bootstrap Modal , Page becomes unclickable

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap Modal.
Once I close the Modal I am unable to click any links/buttons on the page and only after refreshing the page I am able to click again.
I am using below code to hide the modal, backdrop and remove the class from body element but still not able to click anything.

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/individual/viewindividualdetail/" + entryIdForEncryption + "?desigStatus=" + type,
            data:data,
            success:function(response){     
                var modalStr = '<div id="inddetail_new" class="modal"><div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom:0;"><button type="button" class="close indModalClose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></div><div class="modal-body" style="overflow-x:hidden;width:100%;border:0;margin:0;padding:0 15px;height:340px;">' + response+ ' <button class="btn offset2 indModalClose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button></div></div>'; 
                $("#processing").hide();            
                $(modalStr).modal();                    
                
                 $(".indModalClose").off('click').on('click', function () {
                        $('#inddetail_new').modal('hide');
                        $('#inddetail_new').remove();   
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();  
                        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                 });
            },
            error:function(error){
                $("#processing").hide();
                console.log("View Individual Details error", error);
            }           
        })
```

Comment: please post the full code.

Comment: If you have properly implemented Bootstrap css and js, then your first line is all that should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This peace of code could be responsible. Don't off your click event. If you have to make sure to use proper delegate.  Try remove `.off('click')` and then check. if your click event works or not.

```
                $(".indModalClose").off('click').on('click', function () {
                        $('#inddetail_new').modal('hide');
                        $('#inddetail_new').remove();   
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();  
                        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                 });
```

Comment: Click event is working because modal is getting closed, but issue is with the overlay or something which is not allowing for other button clicks.

Comment: No, I am asking you to check after closing model check if you click event are working. 
try this. 
$(".indModalClose").on('click', function () {
                        $('#inddetail_new').modal('hide');
                        $('#inddetail_new').remove();   
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();  
                        $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                 });

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this part:

```js
$("#processing").hide();            
$(modalStr).modal();
```

This won't work, because bs-modal has a fade-in, and fade-out time.

**Solution**:
You have to wait for the first modal to be fully hidden.

```js
$("#processing").on('hidden.bs.modal', () =>
  $(modalStr).modal();
  // Other code
);      
$("#processing").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link and it worked for me using a bootstrap modal in wordpress.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63864849/12964268

```
.modal-backdrop {
display: none;
z-index: 1040 !important;
}

.modal-content {
margin: 2px auto;
z-index: 1100 !important;
}
```