Modal Popup in ASP.NET Core Working but Show like Hidden can't client on pop
i follow steps this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP3xr86IoRU&ab_channel=CodingWorld
but after fished code it working like hidden can click on pop
this is problem

I'm trying to write the code and search but not working however i change to writer like form but not working
any ideas brothers !

this my code on POP window
@model LeadModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_FollowupPartialView";
}


<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="@("follwUp"+Model.LeadId)"
     aria-labelledby="followUpLable" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:100px;">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="follwUpLabel">
                    Follow up
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                        onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">


                <form asp-action="FollowUp">

                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label asp-for="LeadNumber" class="control-label"></label>

                        <input type="number" asp-for="@Model.LeadNumber" style="width:200px;"
                               class="form-control" readonly>


                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label asp-for="LeadName" class="control-label"></label>

                        <input type="text" asp-for="LeadName" class="form-control" style="width:200px;" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="LeadName" class="text-danger"></span>

                    </div>

                    @*  /////////////// *@

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>

                </form>




            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>



when click "follow up" pop working
this my code on model on "follow up" button


I found this and it's Working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292673/bootstrap-modal-opens-but-stays-in-gray-background-and-cannot-close-or-interact
